# Google Sheets Query - Returning the rows that make up the largest 75% of the total sum

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Google Sheets Query that will return 75% of the largest values of the total sum. Essentially, using sales data from many different locations, trying to find the 20% of locations that provide 75% of the revenue.

For example:

```
Store     Revenue
1         225
2         350
3         3000
4         200
5         500
6         600
7         30
8         5000
9         1500
```

Should return

```
Store    Revenue
3        3000
8        5000
```

Here's a Google Sheets in case it helps: https://docs.google.com/a/ash-asia.com/spreadsheets/d/removed

Any ideas on where I should start? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about [ABC-Analyse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC-Analyse)

## In Google Sheets

You may get the report with 2 formulas. Final result:

[image]

Formula for D1:

`=QUERY({A:B},"select Col1, Col2 order by Col2 desc")`

will produce the result in range D1:E10.

Formula is cell F2:

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  ArrayFormula(SUMIF(ROW(E2:E),"<="&ROW(E2:E),E2:E) / sum(E2:E) ) , 
 COUNTA(E2:E) , 1)`

- `SUMIF(ROW(E2:E),"<="&ROW(E2:E),E2:E)` gives [cumulative sum](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37799/cumulative-sum-without-script) by column E.
- `/ sum(E2:E)` devides by total
- `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` limits the result to specific range. The range has `COUNTA(E2:E)` rows and `1` column.

Comment: What's the significance of `COUNTA`?

Comment: @anonymous-rabbit, It is number of rows in `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`

Comment: I see. Thanks. 

Comment: Perfect, this worked great, truly appreciated, really! 
I ended up using these two formulas to extract the data, and then a general query displaying all the data until 0.75% was reached. 

=Query(D:F,"select D, F where (F<0.75)",0)